# Set a default integer value with #ajax, according to a form state value in the same form

Tags: ajax, 9

There is an integer field: "Number of pitches"
Another integer field: "Maximum people allowed".
These will usually be the same values.

I am trying to set the value of the field specified in the pitches, as the default value for the maximum number of people.Whatever combination I try, no results. In a hook_form_alter I try to realize this with Ajax.

```
function zaal_condities_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'node_bedrijf_form' || $form_id == 'node_bedrijf_edit_form'){
   $form['field_staanplaatsen']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'zaal_condities_AjaxCallback',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'edit-field-staanplaatsen-0-value',
    ];
  }
}

function zaal_condities_AjaxCallback(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_state->getValue('field_staanplaatsen') != false){
    $inputValue = $form_state->getValue('field_staanplaatsen');
    return $form['field_bezetting_tot']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $inputValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript API / AJAX Forms](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/ajax-forms) is quite complete and good. Plus, there are many examples around.

Anyway, tthere are various errors.

1. The ajax callback should be attached with code like `$form['your_field']['widget']['#ajax']= [...];`
2. You should set the wrapper using an ID that's kept the same even after AJAX calls. A common solution can be to set up it using `#prefix` and `#suffix`

   ```php
   $form["field_second_field"]["#prefix"] = '<div id="my-id">';
   $form["field_second_field"]["#suffix"] = '</div>';
   ```
3. The AJAX callback should return a renderable array or an AJAX command; in this case, `return $form['field_second_field']`

Written as the following, it should work.

```php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['your_field']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'custom_callback',
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'custom-id',
  ];

  $form["second_field"]["#prefix"] = "<div id='custom-id'>";
  $form["second_field"]["#suffix"] = "</div";
}

function custom_callback(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  //your logic
  return $form["second_field"];
}
```

Please note, I never changed the `#default_value` inside the AJAX callback, but I see no reason why it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with the code below.

In the hook form alter :

```
$form['field_custom_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'my_AjaxCallback',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'edit-field-custom-name-0-value',
    ];
  }
}
```

In the AjaxCallback :

```
if (!empty($form_state->getValue('field_custom_name')[0]['value'])) {

    
    $myvariable = $form_state->getValue('field_custom_name')[0]['value'];
    
        $response = new AjaxResponse();

        $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-custom-name-0-value', 'val', [$myvariable]));

        return $response;
```